# This regex doesn't work for CDATA in xml. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, xml, regex

I'm using an external API which we only allow me regexes, I wanted to parse content from a xml tag like `<name>alwin</name>` and i used `<.*?>.*?<.*/>` to parse "alwin" .. and it doesn't work, but now it is structured like `<name><![CDATA[<table>alwin</table>]]</name>` and I want to be able to parse the CDATA too .. I want to extract `[![CDATA[<table>alwin</table]]` as well. And just "alwin" too.

Comment: See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pattern instead:

```
<([a-zA-Z]+).*?>(.*?)</\1>
```

The `\1` clause targets the first matching group of the pattern, i.e. `([a-zA-Z]+)`. Thus, the matched closing tag will always be the same as the opening one.

The content of the tag will then be available in the second group:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([a-zA-Z]+).*?>(.*?)</\\1>");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<name><![CDATA[<table>alwin</table>]]</name>");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

The above snippet prints:

```
<![CDATA[<table>alwin</table>]]
```

Reiterate the pattern on the above output to get the `alwin` part.

Comment: This approach will fail for `<foo><![CDATA[<foo></foo>]]></foo>` because it will match the outer <foo> against the </foo> inside the CDATA. It will also fail for ordinarily nested identical tags even ignoring the CDATA issue.