# A regex to extract xml tags including xml tags that might have CDATA markup

Tags: java, regex

I usually have xml tags in my strings. But now I have a tag that contains some html markup. A String can contain, `<hg>This is text</hg>` or `<html><![CDATA[<table>this is table</table>]]</html>`. I want to only replace the outertags with an empty string. So, in the first case, `<hg></hg>` will be replaced by empty strings, and in the second `<html></html>` will  be replaced by empty strings. I am using an external api and can only use regexes for this? I tried

```
String retVal = original.replace("`<.*?>.*</.*>`",""); but it didn't work.
```

EDIT:

I want the result to be produced as `<!CDATA[[<table>winter</table>]]> String original = "<html><![CDATA[[<table>winter</table>]]></html>" String retval = original.replaceAll("<([^>]*)>(?:[^<]|<!\[CDATA\[.*?]]>)*</\\1>", "");`

Comment: Duplicate question: answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2239956

Comment: That didn't help me because the regex given there said Caveat: I should note that this regex still breaks down in the presence of CDATA blocks, comments, and script and style elements. Good news is, you can get rid of those using a regex...

Comment: @drquicksilver Thanks for the automatic reply, still as useful. What was the output? Could you rephrase what you're doing? "*I want to only replace the outertags with an empty string.[...]*" I don't really get it.

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15943220/1225328) didn't suit your previous question? Why reasking a new one?

Comment: Could you show us some examples of input data and expected output? What should happen for lets say: `"<html>A<hg>B<table>C</table>D</hg>E</html>"`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @Loamhoof. I honestly think that any attempt to correctly match XML tags whilst correctly accounting for CDATA blocks using a regex is doomed to failure, hence my pointing to a generic answer on the impossibility of this kind of approach. There are probably more useful resources for convincing of the impossibility, I suppose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [This regex doesn't work for CDATA in xml. How do I fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940576/this-regex-doesnt-work-for-cdata-in-xml-how-do-i-fix-this)

Comment: it isn't a duplicate .. i want to replace only the outermost html tags with an empty string and not extract cdata.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no nested tags of the same type, you could use

```
String retVal = original.replaceAll(
    "(?s)<(\\w+)(?: [^>]*)?>(\\s*<!\\[CDATA\\[.*?\\]\\]>\\s*|.*?)</\\1>", "$2"
);
```

`(?s)` turns on singleline mode so `.` also matches newline characters.
`\\1` is whatever was matched by `(\\w+)`, i.e. it's the tag name.
`$2` is the content within the tags.

Comment: what if there is a nested tag <html></html2> some content </html2></html> ... ? How do I modify this expression to only extract, "some content"

Comment: @Phoenix. There are various options, one of which is to apply the regex on the string a second time, or in a loop. It would be easier just to match any content that is not tags, but that is not the question you originally asked. You need to specify your requirements in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String retVal = original.replace("<([^>]*)>([^<]|<!\\[CDATA\\[.*?]]>)*</\\1>","$2");
```

Still, it your tag has attributes, it'll fail (can change it to adapt though).

**Edit:**
Edited as I hadn't seen the flaw in your example. You're missing a ">" at the end of your CDATA.

Comment: It doesn't work on the example below. I want the result to be produced as <!CDATA[[<table>winter</table>]]>                       String original = "<html><![CDATA[[<table>winter</table>]]></html>"
    String retval = original.replaceAll("<([^>]*)>(?:[^<]|<!\\[CDATA\\[.*?]]>)*</\\1>", "");

Comment: Well, you just have to capture the string. Edited accordingly (simply made a group capturing).

Comment: It is printing the entire string.

Comment: `replace` doesn't take a regex, you need `replaceAll` or `replaceFirst`.

Answer (score 0):

The task seems to be too complex for regex, I can offer only an algorithic solution

```
    String s = "<hg>This is text</hg> or <html><![CDATA[<table>this is table</table>]]</html>.";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i != -1;){
        i = s.indexOf("<![CDATA[", i);
        if (i != -1) {
            sb.append(s.substring(0, i).replaceAll("<.*?>", ""));
            int j = s.indexOf("]]");
            sb.append(s.substring(i + 9, j));
            s = s.substring(j + 2);
            i = 0;
        } 
    }
    sb.append(s.replaceAll("<.*?>", ""));
    System.out.println(sb);
```

output

```
This is text or <table>this is table</table>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following example is in C#. Modify it for Java.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"<(\w+)>(.*)</\1>", "$2");
```

Answer (score -1):

"(?(?!])"

this should match what you want if i understand you and use replaceAll method
from your example it only matches  and